# How to import PostGIS into BigQuery GIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, shapely, well-known-binary, google-big-query

I have to import PostGIS data into BigQuery GIS.
In order to do this, I dumped the PostGIS data in CSV and import it into BigQuery.
This is working for all the columns but not the geometric one.

If I understood well, this is because BigQuery GIS is not supporting EWKB. In the CSV dump, a data point is encoded like:

```
01010000206A080000C88758C0E72B1441EE517105E8185A41
```

As an example, of what I think is the EWKB problem, when I'm using the python package [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io) for converting a Hex WKB geometry:

```py
from shapely import wkb
print(wkb.loads("01010000206A080000C88758C0E72B1441EE517105E8185A41", hex=True))
```

this will give the right location

```bsh
POINT (330489.9378377167 6841248.085041506)
```

But with [BigQuery GIS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-intro) using:

```sql
SELECT ST_GEOGFROM("01010000206A080000C88758C0E72B1441EE517105E8185A41") AS WKT_format
```

I have the following error:

```bsh
ST_GeogFrom failed: Unknown object type 0x20000001; during WKB parsing
```

What could be a reliable pipeline for importing PostGIS data into BigQuery GIS?

Comment: WKT and GeoJSON are at least easier for you because they are also human-readable https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data.

Comment: By the link presented in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228645/invalid-gis-data-provided-to-function-st-geometryfromwkb 0x20000001 stands for "point with srid". I think that EWKB should be converted into WKB. Or the dump should be re-created by using ST_AsBinary postgis.net/docs/ST_AsBinary.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems that would prevent loading this data directly to BigQuery.

1. this is EWKB, extended WKB with SRID (this is what [0x20000001 is](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-devel/2004-December/000710.html)). BigQuery does not understand this extension.
2. BigQuery only supports WGS 84 (also known SRID EPSG:4326) - or to put it simply, `POINT(longitude latitude)` while the values `POINT (330489.9378377167 6841248.085041506)` are clearly not longitude and latitude.

What you can do to get this into format BigQuery understands is project it to SRID 4326, and export to some text format, [GeoJson being safer choice](https://mentin.medium.com/loading-large-spatial-features-to-bigquery-geography-2f6ceb6796df):

```sql
ST_AsGeoJson( ST_Transform( geog_column, 4326 ))
```